# Django wagtail adding favicon to root page

Tags: django, wagtail

I think adding a favicon field for all the page models is not a good way.

How can we customize the settings/sites root page to have an image field for favicon?

Answer (score 1):

The [wagtail.contrib.settings](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/reference/contrib/settings.html) module will let you set up properties such as favicon on a per-site basis.

Comment: Don't you think that the favicon field should be in site edit form?